# Monthly average of new users by business day

Tags: tableau-api

My data consists of `fully_enrolled_at` as dimension and `new_users` as measure. Therefore, this doesn't require a dataset, since any date and measure you can `sum()` will do.

I created the following 2 calculations:

## this is number of calendar days in the month

```
days_in_month = DATEDIFF('day',MIN(DATETRUNC('month',[fully_enrolled_at])),MAX(DATETRUNC('month',DATEADD('month',1,[fully_enrolled_at]))))
```

## this changes number of calendar days in the current month to the number of days elapsed:

```
days_in_all_months = IF MIN(DATETRUNC('month',today()))=MAX(DATETRUNC('month',[fully_enrolled_at])) THEN 1+DATEDIFF('day',DATETRUNC('month',today()),today()) ELSE [days_in_month] END
```

Then I plotted: `discrete month(fully_enrolled_at) as dimension, and sum([new_users])/[days_in_all_months]` as measure.

This gives me what I am looking for, however I would like to account for business days in each of the months, not calendar month.

How do I remove weekends and national holidays from `days_in_all_months` (while current month should have # of business days elapsed)?
Holiday's list: https://gist.github.com/jameslin101/cf2860eba52a56281427#file-csv-of-us-stock-market-holidays-through-2020

Can you assist with adjusting this? Thank you!

Comment: Options 2 + 3 solved my problem: https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/calculating-the-number-of-business-days-in-a-month

Answer (score 0):

You could set the current **Day** and  **WorkingDaysTotal**. Then include an **IF** statement.

*If Day = Saturday or Sunday do nothing else WorkingDaysTotal = WorkingDaysTotal + 1*

This in theory would give you the amount of working days.

You would also need:

*If first day of the month then WorkingDaysTotal = 0*

And finally, check to see if the first day of the month is a Saturday or Sunday again.

National holidays would be more tricky, as different countries, religions etc have different holidays. So you would have to set these dates prior.

**EDIT**

Here is a work example of what you are wanting, excluding Holidays and Weekends.

```
=AVERAGE(IF(WEEKDAY(C7:I7,2)<6,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C7:I7,Holidays,FALSE)),C8:I8)))

where C7:I7 has the dates, C8:I8 has the data, and Holidays is a named range of holiday dates. If you further want to exclude 0 values, then use this array formula

=AVERAGE(IF(WEEKDAY(C7:I7,2)<6,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C7:I7,Holidays,FALSE)),IF(C8:I8>0,C8:I8))))
```

Comment: The logic is obvious, application isn't. Also the holidays are important

Comment: Sarcasm doesn’t get you far in a **help** community. Stating what language you are using would be a logical thing to do. I have edited my answer to do exactly what you are wanting in regards to excluding business days and holidays... in Excel.

Comment: The language is specified - it is Tableau, not Excel.. and with all due respect, this isn't sarcasm: "remove 2 days a week to get weekday" isn't an answer

Comment: Include your specific holidays. If you include **Today’s Day**, and check what day it is, then you can skip Saturdays & Sunday’s quite easily. Which will give you your **Total Working Days** for that month - the specific holidays. I am unfamiliar with tableau, however most languages are based on similar concepts, and many sub-languages on their parents. So I’m still happy to help.